# Magento cart item html not render after upgrade 1.7 to 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, theme

I have upgrade magento from `1.7 to 1.9.2.4`, everything is working good but I am getting issue with magento cart items are not showing in the cart but product total and other things are fine.

> this was before upgrade

[image: like]

> After upgrade it is showing like

[image]

I have checked code with my `app/design/frontend/theme-xx/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml`

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
       <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

What is the possible reason for issue? how to fix this?

Comment: Does that happen if you switch to the native Magento `default/default` theme?

Comment: same issue with `default/default` please check screenshot, https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/453246/42tfgx0m1ny932vk9n2n

Comment: any solution for this? anyone